# Как сложить данные в массиве (цикл)

Tags: javascript, циклы, ejs

```
<% for(var sum in games[key].bets) {%>
   <% for(var summ in games[key].bets[sum].items) {%>
      <% { var items_sum = 0; 
           items_sum += games[key].bets[sum].items[summ].price }  %>
      <%- items_sum  %>
   <% } %>
<% } %>%
```

Результат отдает вот такой: 30 30 30
А нужен 90. (Сложить все значения в bets.items.price)
Массив такого вида:

```
games =  
[{bets: {
        items: [{
            id: 1 price: 30
        }, {
            id: 4,
            price: 30
        }, {
            id: 3,
            price: 30
        }]
    }},
    {bets: {
        items: [{
            id: 1,
            price: 50
        }, {
            id: 4,
            price: 50
        }, {
            id: 3,
            price: 50
        }]
    }}]
```

Comment: вынеси `var items_sum = 0;` на уровень выше, перед `for(var summ in games[key].bets[sum].items`

Comment: +, результаты теперь такие 30 60 90 вывести над только третий

Comment: Таки и выводи только последний. не вижу проблем. смотришь когда итерация равна длине массива - 1 и выводишь

Comment: Не совсем понял как мне именно вывести последнее значение. Обьектов может быть хоть 100, и выводить соотвественно надо последний.

Comment: `смотришь когда итерация равна длине массива - 1 и выводишь` - что именно не ясно в этой фразе? массив у тебя размером N. Когда `итерация = N-1` — выводишь сумму

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос программирования очень будет полезно прикрепить теги языка программирования к вопросу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно было вынести объявление переменной за цикл и так же вывод это переменной за цикл, тогда выведет то что вам надо:

```
<% var items_sum = 0; %>
<% for(var sum in games[key].bets) {%>
   <% for(var summ in games[key].bets[sum].items) {%>
      <% items_sum += games[key].bets[sum].items[summ].price  %>
   <% } %>
<% } %>%
<%- items_sum  %>
```

Comment: Код выдает результат: 30 60 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @kiLLro обновил ответ, пробуйте

Comment: Работает, спасибо!